# object 'x' not found when using tm_shape, but object exists?

Tags: r, object, r-sf, r-sp, tmap

I'm trying to make maps showing each country's score for a human rights index using tmap. tmap only has a few shapes that can be used ('nz' for New Zealand, 'world' for the whole world, and one or two more), so I'm using a shapefile from rnaturalearth that I merged with my existing dataframe so that I can make maps using my data on the rnaturalearth shapes. However, when I use the function `tm_shape(Afghanistan)` and `tm(fill)` to make a basic map of Afghanistan, I get the error

```
Error in as.list.environment(environment()) : 
  object 'Afghanistan' not found
```

My code for downloading the rnaturalearth shapefile, which i named 'country50'

```
install.packages("rnaturalearth")
install.packages("rnaturalearthdata")
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata) 
country50 <- ne_download(scale = 50, type = 'countries', category = 'cultural')
```

Merging 'country50' with my preexisting dataframe on 'NAME_LONG' to create 'ciri2014.country50.merged'

```
ciri2014.country50.merged = merge(country50, CIRI_Data_1981_2011_2014_04_14, by = 'NAME_LONG', duplicateGeoms = TRUE)
```

At this point, this should work, because the variable 'Afghanistan' is in the original dataframe that I merged with 'country50' but instead I get this

```
tm_shape(Afghanistan) + tm_fill()
 Error in as.list.environment(environment()) : 
  object 'Afghanistan' not found
```

I then realized that 'ciri2014.country50.merged' was an S4 file, so I did this to make it an sf file

```
st_as_sf(ciri2014.country50.merged)
Simple feature collection with 5492 features and 195 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -180 ymin: -89.99893 xmax: 180 ymax: 83.59961
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
First 10 features:

#  and so on.
```

Next, I did this

```
sf.ciri2014.country50.merged = st_as_sf(ciri2014.country50.merged)
> View(sf.ciri2014.country50.merged)
> tm_shape(Afghanistan) + tm_fill()
Error in as.list.environment(environment()) : 
  object 'Afghanistan' not found

> map.sf.ciri2014.country50.merged = st_as_sf(ciri2014.country50.merged, fill = TRUE, group = TRUE)
> View(map.sf.ciri2014.country50.merged)
> tm_shape(Afghanistan) + tm_fill()

Error in as.list.environment(environment()) : 
  object 'Afghanistan' not found
```

The object 'Afghanistan' definitely exists but I don't know why `tmap` isn't able to find it. I've also tried the country code and the abbreviations for multiple countries with the same result. The only maps I can make are of New Zealand or the whole world. Am I missing something painfully obvious? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You've not got an "object" called `Afghanistan` - you've got an "object" called `country50` which has one row (or one feature) that is represents Afghanistan. To draw just that, extract it into an object with whatever name you want, `Afghanistan` will do, and map that:

```
> Afghanistan = country50[country50$NAME=="Afghanistan",]
> library(tmap);tm_shape(Afghanistan) + tm_fill()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you so much!!! It worked perfectly and FINALLY I can move forward with this project. You are a lifesaver!!!